# how to find if an image exists or not in tpl files (smarty)?

Tags: php, smarty

I have to check that if a file exists at the given path or not. I tried using file_exists but it doesnt work with my version of smarty. Please suggest me how can i check whether an image exists at a given path or not??

Comment: Plese write your smarty version.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this:

```
{assign var="image_name" value=$article.item_manufacturer|lower}
{assign var="image"
value="/home/sunflyer/public_html/media/manufacturer/$image_name.gif"}
{if file_exists($image)}
```